# Symfony2 undefined service parameter

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

My service configuration is:

```
<services>
    <service id="my_service" class="Acme\HelloBundle\Hello">
        <argument type="service" id="search" on-invalid="null" />
        <argument>%other_bundle.class_name%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

When service "search" is not defined I get null (thanks on-invalid="null").

But what if parameter *%other_bundle.class_name%* is not defined in this case I got error. Is any option what set to: `<argument>%other_bundle.class_name%</argument>`
that when parameter not exists I get null or empty string?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any real-world scenario where parameter would not be defined at all?

Comment: is a parameters and can be overridden by configuration, so i suggest you to simple define a default value for it.

Comment: Parameter would not be defined at all when is defined in other bundle and the budle is not enabled.

Parameters can be overriden, thats true, but when I enable "Other" bundle with correct value earlier than this bundle with default parameter value I will get default value, so I don't want only rely on order of bundle enable. So I looking for option how set defalt emty value for parameter in  <argument>%other_bundle.class_name%</argument>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **might** be able to do it via expression language:

Following the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language) for injecting services via expressions, I believe the same can be applied to parameters:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer
        arguments:    ["@=parameter('other_bundle.class_name') ?: null"]
```

**I don't like it**, as it really feels dirty but if you really need it, nobody can argue ;)

Hope this helps...

Comment: this doesn't work: parameter condition call the `getParameter` method on the container. The method ``hasParametes` is not mapped by default in the expression language for container but can be custom defined.

Comment: Jovan this looks good, but it from version 2.4 and I'm using 2.3.
I solved it for now with: Compiler Passes.